# Return an php array to jquery ajax and populating a list. With some if()'s

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Trying to make an ajax driven, sortable contact list.
A menu with 3 alternatives should upon click render a new list with updated data.

Been searching around a bit but havn't found any good info on this (as from what I understand atleast..)

---

This is what populates my list at the moment. I know, bad choice of variables..

```
        <?php
            if($c['ischeckedin'])
            {
                $checkedin='Check Out';
                $checked='checkedin';} 
            else{
                $checkedin='Check In';
                $checked='';}
        ?>

        <li id="<?php print $c['id']; ?>" class="clearfix gradient1 <?php print $checked; ?>">
            <?php print $c['name']; ?>

            <img src="options.png" class="options rounded3" alt="options" width="16" height="16" />

            <?php if($c['ischeckedin']): ?>
                <input 
                        type="button" 
                        class="button checkerout" 
                        value="<?php print $checkedin; ?>" 
                        name="<?php print $c['id']; ?>" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <input 
                    type="button" 
                    class="button checkerin" 
                    value="<?php print $checkedin; ?>" 
                    name="<?php print $c['id']; ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>   

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So basicly it's a list of contacts. Some are checked in, therefore the different classes and buttons. (Any cleaner suggestions are more than welcome!)

But now I need to populate the list via Ajax, since I need to be able to sort it. So I send some more data along with the call and my php/mysql returns some filtered data.

`<li>` - 
`ID` should be the id from the db.
`class` needs to differ between 'checkedin' and '' depending on result from mysql.

`<input>` - 
`class` should be 'checkerin' or 'checkerout' depending on result from mysql.
`name` should be the id from the db.

---

The problem, what do I do with the returned data from php -> ajax -> print?

And how do I translate all those nasty if()'s so that I can make difference amongst checked and nonchecked contacts? Edit it before returning it?

Answer (score 0):

Let php create the data as an associative array and return it to the ajax as a json_encoded string, then walk through the json and create your list.  Or, you could have the ajax return the already created page and populate your div with that info, just make sure you set the option on the ajax call to allow javascript to execute if you need it to.

Comment: Php's already doing that. I just get an array into my ajax function which I don't really know what to do with. How would I pre-populate the list btw?